# How to disable tomcat access logs with springboot and cloud foundry

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, cloud-foundry

```
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.10.Final:compile
[INFO] | | \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.0.3.RELEASE:provided
[INFO] | +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] | +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.31:provided
[INFO] | +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.31:provided
[INFO] | \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.31:provided
```

That above is the spring version I am using

```
2018-10-12T11:19:34.78-0500 [RTR/1] OUT
2018-10-12T11:19:34.80-0500 [RTR/1] OUT myapp-dev.apps.pcf.company.com ...
[2018-10-12T16:19:34.778+0000] "OPTIONS /cloudfoundryapplication/mappings HTTP/1.1" 200 0 0 "-" ...
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36" "10.126.5.247:49163" "10.212.58.166:61054" x_forwarded_for:"10.45.137.38, 10.126.5.247" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"24d40ced-4982-41dd-559d-3fbde7165eb1" response_time:0.016173018 app_id:"b26f4acb-b78c-4d9f-909c-de4edec9725b" app_index:"0" x_b3_traceid:"c328e8e59f70beb7" x_b3_spanid:"c328e8e59f70beb7" x_b3_parentspanid:"-"
```

What logger is it that logs this request?

Is there any way to ignore this request from being logged in pcf?

By the way this is not logback logging because those look like this

```
2018-10-12T12:23:25.08-0500 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT vehicle360 12-10-2018 17:23:25.087 ... 
[http-nio-8080-exec-7] INFO  com.mycompany.vehicle360.logging.LoggingAspect.logExecutionTime:21 - VehicleDTO com.mycompany.vehicle360.service.Vehicle360GDAASService.getVinDetails(String,String,String) executed in 1398ms
```

Comment: Please format it!

Comment: @Boris I tried now

Comment: Thanks, it's much easier to read it now. Have you tried to configure [log levels](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels)? Maybe `logging.level.root=WARN`?

Comment: If you notice, this is not java logger logging, my root it set to ERROR , and if logback logs it will have classname line number and that sort of thing

Comment: I think its coming from here but I cant disable it https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack-support/blob/master/tomcat-logging-support/src/main/java/org/cloudfoundry/tomcat/logging/CloudFoundryFormatter.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logs you see are emitted by the router when it routes HTTP requests to the app. See [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/streaming-logs.html#rtr) for more info.

I don't know if there is a way to disable the router logs, but you can filter it out:

```
$ cf logs APP-NAME --recent | grep -v RTR
```

Comment: It's not possible to turn off Gorouter access logs. You really don't want to either. The information in access logs is invaluable when troubleshooting and monitoring for users that are doing things they should not be (like bots or malicious users). Don't ever turn off access logs. If you don't want to look at them, just filter them out like is described here.